# HTML and CSS Menú Issue

Tags: html, css, menu

Im doing [this web](http://com10.raiolanetworks.es/~aquafide/) with Wordpress and one theme but i have a problem with a transition to the submenus.

If you can check the "QUÉ HACEMOS" submenu, you will see that when i try to click on an element of submenú if imposible by the margin top, do you understand ?

If i delete the 38px margin top of sub-menu class no problem, but I need that the submenú start and header border but i have this problem that i cant fix, please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please post the code you are editing.

Comment: Can you paste some code in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the following definitions in your CSS and edit respectively

```
.main-nav > li > a {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 37px 25px;
}


li:not(.dt-mega-menu) .sub-nav {
    width: 280px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background: #043349;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot miro!